# Syntax for INSERT INTO SELECT statement

Tags: sql

I have a table with an Identity column (ArticleID).  I would like to select the last row in the table and insert a value into a particular column (ArticleImage).  I already have the value, so I needn't query for it.  Where in the SQL statement do I place this value?

```
INSERT INTO EasyDNNNews (ArticleImage)
SELECT TOP 1 FROM EasyDNNNews
ORDER BY ArticleID DESC
```

Comment: so, you don't want to **insert** a new row, you want to **update** one (the hints for your answer are in the bolded words)

Comment: What SQL - MySQL, MS-Access, SQL Server ? Answers sometimes vary based on product

Comment: @Lamk...you are correct.  I am updating a record.  Thanks!

Comment: Armed with Lamak's sagely comment, have you googled 'SQL Update'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like commentator's have hinted, you need an UPDATE statement, not an INSERT. UPDATE, updates a record that already exists, where INSERT creates a whole brand spanking new record.

Yours is a little more complicated than just a `UPDATE <table> SET <field>='Somevalue';` since you want to update a specific record based on a sort. You were headed in the right direction with your `SELECT TOP 1..` query.

```
UPDATE EasyDNNNews 
SET ArticleImage = 'YOURVALUE' 
WHERE ArticleID = (SELECT TOP 1 ArticleID FROM EasyDNNNews ORDER BY ArticleID Desc)`
```

That subquery fetches the max `ArticleID`. The outer UPDATE statement then updates that Articleid's record, setting ArticleImage to whatever value you want to stick in there.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a subquery or updatable CTE:

```
WITH toupdate as (
      SELECT TOP 1 d.*
      FROM EasyDNNNews d
      ORDER BY ArticleID DESC
     )
UPDATE toupdate
     SET ArticleImage = ??;
```

Comment: I didn't know updatable CTE was even a thing. That is very handy.